# R : Browsing files in a folder and extracting names and data from it

Tags: r, regex, gsub, grepl

I need to extract some data from spreadsheets, there are many of them (more than a hundred) so I thought it would be faster to do that with some R script. (Maybe that is [my first error](https://xkcd.com/1319/), but I would like to give it a try and improve myself at manipulating files and data using R.)

All these files are in the same folders, most of them have name of a meteorological station or city, only some files are irrelevant. Moreover they don't have all the same extensions: some are .csv, other .xls, some .txt, .zip or .r (those are the unwanted files)

**What I want to do** is to browse my folder, pick the name of the file if it's relevant to me, only keep the name of the city/station, open the file, gather the information I need, close it and go to the next file.

Also, some cities have several stations or there are several files for the same station. For instance:

```
SomeCity.csv and SomeCity_1966-2001.csv
AnotherCity.station1.xls, AnotherCity.station2.xls
ACity.station.xls, ACity_1977-2005.csv
My.City.csv, My-City.csv
```

So yeah, it's not always that simple...

Here what I did for the moment, I look only at the .csv and .xls files. If a "_" is present, then I only keep what is before it and stock it if the city is not already in the dataframe, if there is not, then I just remove the extension to get the city name. I need to have these 2 cases regarding the extension of the file because the data inside is not formatted the same way: for instance the station Id is in the first column in .xls whereas it is in the second column in .csv...

```
# Read files names :
files_list <- list.files(path="my/path/to/files")
n_files <- length(files_list)

df_out <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 6, nrow = n_files))
x <- c("Name","Id","Granularity","Start","End","Missing")
colnames(df_out) <- x
i=1
j=1

# Browing the list of files
while(j<n_files)
{
  file = files_list[j]

  # Case of a .csv file  :
  if(grepl(".csv",file))
  {
    if(!grepl("_",file))
    {
      df_out$Name[i] <- gsub("\\.csv","",file)
      i <- i+1
    }
    else if(!any(grepl(gsub("\\_.*","",file),df_out$Name)))
    {
      df_out$Name[i] <- gsub("\\_.*","",file)
      i <- i+1
    }
  }

  # Case of a .xls file :
  else if(grepl(".xls",file))
  {
    if(!grepl("_",file))
    {
      df_out$Nom[i] <- gsub("\\.xls","",file)
      i <- i+1
    }
    else if(!any(grepl(gsub("\\_.*","",file),df_out$Name)))
    {
      df_out$Nom[i] <- gsub("\\_.*","",file)
      i <- i+1
    }
  }
  j <- j+1
}
df_out <- df_out[1:i-1,]
```

**Problem** : in the case of "My.city" and "My-City" I will have 2 different entries in my data frame for the same station, how can I avoid that ? I was thinking about removing the "." or "-" and stock the name as MyCity and look if another MyCity is already here, but that is not very nice to the inhabitants of My-City to deface their city name. 
Just kidding, I just feel that there would be a better way to do it using regex.
To be honest, I feel that most of the things I'm doing could be done in few lines with regex.

Here is the actual list of files I have :

```
"200601.txt"
"Abbeville.xls"
"Abbeville_1971-2005.csv"
"Agen.xls"
"Agen_1961-2005.csv"
"Ajaccio.xls"
"Ajaccio_1961-2003.csv"
"Auxerre.xls"
"Auxerre_1961-2005.csv"
"Bale-Mulhouse_1961-2005.csv"
"Bale.Mulhouse.xls"
"Beauvais_1994-2005.csv"
"Beauvais_2001-2005.csv"
"Besancon.xls"
"Besancon_1961-2005.csv"
"Biarritz.anglet.xls"
"Biarritz_1961-2005.csv"
"Bonneville.xls"
"Bordeaux.Merignac.xls"
"Bordeaux_1961-2005.csv"
"Boulogne_1994-2005.csv"
"Boulogne_2001-2005.csv"
"Bourg-St-Maurice_1994-2005.csv"
"Bourg-St-Maurice_2001-2005.csv"
"Bourges.xls"
"Bourges_1961-2005.csv"
"Brest.Guipavas.xls"
"Brest_1961-2005_sauf_1989.csv"
"Brive.xls"
"Caen.Carpiquet.xls"
"Caen_1961-2005.csv"
"Cap.de.la.Heve.Le.Havre.xls"
"Carcassonne.xls"
"Cazaux.xls"
"Chambery.Aix.xls"
"Chambery_1974-2005.csv"
"Charleville.Mezieres.xls"
"Chartres.xls"
"Chartres_1961-2005.csv"
"Clermond-Fd_1961-2005.csv"
"Clermont.Fd.xls"
"Cognac.xls"
"Cognac_1961-2005.csv"
"Colmar.xls"
"Dijon.xls"
"Dijon_1961-2005.csv"
"Dinard.xls"
"Dinard_1961-2005.csv"
"Dinard_2003-2005.csv"
"donnees_triH_1961_2005.csv
"Dunkerque.txt"
"Dunkerque_1974-2008.csv"
"Embrun.xls"
"Embrun_1961-2005.csv"
"ENVOI_METEO_20040405.zip"
"Gourdon_1994-2005.csv"
"Gourdon_2001-2005.csv"
"Grenoble.le.versoud.xls"
"Grenoble.St.Geoirs.xls"
"Grenoble.St.Martin.heres.xls"
"Grenoble_1968-2005.csv"
"historiques Bordeaux et Dinard.txt"
"Hyeres_2007-2009.csv"
"Istres.csv"
"Istres.txt"
"La-Rochelle_1961-2005.csv"
"La-Rochelle_Aerodrome_2007-2009.csv"
"La.Rochelle.xls"
"Le.Puy.xls"
"Le.Touquet.xls"
"Lille.xls"
"Lille_1961-2005.csv"
"losvari.11069001.txt"
"losvari.14137001.txt"
"losvari.17300001.txt"
"losvari.31069001.txt"
"losvari.33529001.txt"
"losvari.62826001.txt"
"losvari.64549001.txt"
"losvari.76552001.txt"
"losvari.78621001.txt"
"Luxeil.xls"
"Luxeuil_1961-2005.csv"
"Lyon.Bron.xls"
"Lyon_1961-2005.csv"
"Macon_1994-2005.csv"
"Macon_2001-2005.csv"
"Marignane.xls"
"Marignane_1961-2005.csv"
"Metz.Frescaty.xls"
"Metz_1961-2005.csv"
"Millau.xls"
"Mise_en_forme.r"
"Montelimar.xls"
"Montelimar_1961-2005.csv"
"Montpellier.xls"
"Montpellier_1961-2005.csv"
"Nantes.Bouguenais.xls"
"Nantes_1961-2005.csv"
"Nice.xls"
"Nice_1961-2005.csv"
"Nimes.Courbessac.xls"
"Nimes_1961-2005.csv"
"Orange.xls"
"Orange_1961-2005.csv"
"Orleans.xls"
"Orleans_1961-2005.csv"
"Paris_1950-2005.csv"
"Paris1.xls"
"Pau.Uzein.xls"
"Pau_03-2006.csv"
"Pau_1961-2005.csv"
"Perpignan.xls"
"Perpignan_1961-2005.csv"
"Reims.Courcy.xls"
"Reims_1961-2005.csv"
"Rennes.St.Jacques.xls"
"Rennes_1961-2005.csv"
"Rennes_1961-2005_sauf_2003-2004.csv"
"Rennes_2003-2004.csv"
"Rouen.Boos.xls"
"Rouen_1969-2005.csv"
"Saint.Brieuc.xls"
"Saint.Girons.xls"
"St-Etienne_1961-2005.csv"
"St-Girons_1961-2005.csv"
"St-Quentin_1961-2008.csv"
"St.Auban.xls"
"St.Etienne.Boutheon.xls"
"St.Quentin.xls"
"Strasbourg.Entzheim.xls"
"Strasbourg_1949-2005.csv"
"Toulon.xls"
"Toulon_1961-2005.csv"
"Toulouse.Blagnac.xls"
"Toulouse_1961-2005.csv"
"Tours.xls"
"Tours_1960-2005.csv"
```

And here is the output of my code (Id will be easy to get but maybe not the rest...) :

```
                       Name Id Granularity Start End Missing
1                 Abbeville NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
2                      Agen NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
3                   Ajaccio NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
4                   Auxerre NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
5             Bale-Mulhouse NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
6             Bale.Mulhouse NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
7                  Beauvais NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
8                  Besancon NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
9           Biarritz.anglet NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
10               Bonneville NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
11        Bordeaux.Merignac NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
12                 Boulogne NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
13         Bourg-St-Maurice NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
14                  Bourges NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
15           Brest.Guipavas NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
16                    Brive NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
17           Caen.Carpiquet NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
18  Cap.de.la.Heve.Le.Havre NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
19              Carcassonne NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
20                   Cazaux NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
21             Chambery.Aix NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
22     Charleville.Mezieres NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
23                 Chartres NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
24              Clermond-Fd NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
25              Clermont.Fd NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
26                   Cognac NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
27                   Colmar NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
28                    Dijon NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
29                   Dinard NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
30                  donnees NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
31                Dunkerque NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
32                   Embrun NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
33                  Gourdon NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
34      Grenoble.le.versoud NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
35       Grenoble.St.Geoirs NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
36 Grenoble.St.Martin.heres NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
37                   Hyeres NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
38                   Istres NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
39              La-Rochelle NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
40              La.Rochelle NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
41                   Le.Puy NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
42               Le.Touquet NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
43                    Lille NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
44                   Luxeil NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
45                  Luxeuil NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
46                Lyon.Bron NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
47                    Macon NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
48                Marignane NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
49            Metz.Frescaty NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
50                   Millau NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
51               Montelimar NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
52              Montpellier NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
53        Nantes.Bouguenais NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
54                     Nice NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
55         Nimes.Courbessac NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
56                   Orange NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
57                  Orleans NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
58                    Paris NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
59                   Paris1 NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
60                Pau.Uzein NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
61                Perpignan NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
62             Reims.Courcy NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
63        Rennes.St.Jacques NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
64               Rouen.Boos NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
65             Saint.Brieuc NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
66             Saint.Girons NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
67               St-Etienne NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
68                St-Girons NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
69               St-Quentin NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
70                 St.Auban NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
71      St.Etienne.Boutheon NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
72               St.Quentin NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
73      Strasbourg.Entzheim NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
74                   Toulon NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
75         Toulouse.Blagnac NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
76                    Tours NA          NA    NA  NA      NA
```

Thank you for your insights and help.
Regards.

EDIT : expected output for df_out$Name :
(Using Id i will be able to say if Grenoble.St.Geoirs is the same station as Grenoble.St.Martin or not so that's why for now it is still here.)

```
Abbeville
Agen
Ajaccio
Auxerre
Bale-Mulhouse
Beauvais
Besancon
Biarritz.anglet
Biarritz
Bonneville
Bordeaux.Merignac
Bordeaux
Boulogne
Bourg-St-Maurice
Bourges
Brest.Guipavas
Brest
Brive
Caen.Carpiquet
Caen
Cap.de.la.Heve.Le.Havre
Carcassonne
Cazaux
Chambery.Aix
Chambery
Charleville.Mezieres
Chartres
Clermond-Fd
Cognac
Colmar
Dijon
Dinard
Dunkerque
Embrun
Gourdon
Grenoble.le.versoud
Grenoble.St.Geoirs
Grenoble.St.Martin
Grenoble
Hyeres
Istres
La-Rochelle_Aerodrome
La-Rochelle
Le.Puy
Le.Touquet
Lille
Luxeil
Lyon.Bron
Lyon
Macon
Marignane
Metz.Frescaty
Metz
Millau
Montelimar
Montpellier
Nantes.Bouguenais
Nantes
Nice
Nimes.Courbessac
Nimes
Orange
Orleans
Paris
Paris1
Pau.Uzein
Pau
Perpignan
Reims.Courcy
Reims
Rennes.St.Jacques
Rennes
Rouen.Boos
Rouen
Saint.Brieuc
Saint.Girons
St-Etienne
St-Girons
St-Quentin
St.Auban
St.Etienne.Boutheon
Strasbourg.Entzheim
Strasbourg
Toulon
Toulouse.Blagnac
Toulouse
Tours
```

Comment: Given the list of inputs you've presented, what is the expected outcome? Your question is very well-structured for a beginner on SO, well done +1

Comment: Thank you, well, I would need a similar output but without the Bale-Mulhouse AND Bale.Mulhouse (for instance) in my dataframe , only a Bale-Mulhouse.

Comment: So basically all instances where the names are the same but the separator creates 2 entries? So `Clermond-Fd` should exist while `Clermont.Fd` should not?

Comment: Yes exactly ! (I added an explicit expected output in the post.)

Comment: What about `donnes_triH`, `ENVOI_METEO`, `heres` in `Grenoble.St.Martin.heres`, `historique Bordeaux et Dinard`, `losvari`, `Luxeuil` (2 spellings), `Mise_en_forme`, `St.Quentin` (you this and `St-Quentin` as being valid output)? I have the correct answer apart from these oddities.

Comment: Also `Clermont.Fd` and `Clermond-Fd` (`t` vs `d`)

Comment: Damn I didn't see that difference for Clermont/d, well it's just a mistake when they named the file...

Comment: Yes there are extra csv files that I don't need (those donnees_triH, ENVOI_METEO etc), but I don't see a way to put them apart while browsing. I can tell that I don't want them but not R... I think I will try another way, maybe by opening them first, getting their Id and gathering them according to the Id. (But again I may have trouble because of those unwanted files :( ) Maybe full automation isn't the solution here, I should first gather all the files I want and renamed them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Code

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/yflKPd)

```
x <- c("200601.txt","Abbeville.xls","Abbeville_1971-2005.csv","Agen.xls","Agen_1961-2005.csv","Ajaccio.xls","Ajaccio_1961-2003.csv","Auxerre.xls","Auxerre_1961-2005.csv","Bale-Mulhouse_1961-2005.csv","Bale.Mulhouse.xls","Beauvais_1994-2005.csv","Beauvais_2001-2005.csv","Besancon.xls","Besancon_1961-2005.csv","Biarritz.anglet.xls","Biarritz_1961-2005.csv","Bonneville.xls","Bordeaux.Merignac.xls","Bordeaux_1961-2005.csv","Boulogne_1994-2005.csv","Boulogne_2001-2005.csv","Bourg-St-Maurice_1994-2005.csv","Bourg-St-Maurice_2001-2005.csv","Bourges.xls","Bourges_1961-2005.csv","Brest.Guipavas.xls","Brest_1961-2005_sauf_1989.csv","Brive.xls","Caen.Carpiquet.xls","Caen_1961-2005.csv","Cap.de.la.Heve.Le.Havre.xls","Carcassonne.xls","Cazaux.xls","Chambery.Aix.xls","Chambery_1974-2005.csv","Charleville.Mezieres.xls","Chartres.xls","Chartres_1961-2005.csv","Clermond-Fd_1961-2005.csv","Clermont.Fd.xls","Cognac.xls","Cognac_1961-2005.csv","Colmar.xls","Dijon.xls","Dijon_1961-2005.csv","Dinard.xls","Dinard_1961-2005.csv","Dinard_2003-2005.csv","donnees_triH_1961_2005.csv","Dunkerque.txt","Dunkerque_1974-2008.csv","Embrun.xls","Embrun_1961-2005.csv","ENVOI_METEO_20040405.zip","Gourdon_1994-2005.csv","Gourdon_2001-2005.csv","Grenoble.le.versoud.xls","Grenoble.St.Geoirs.xls","Grenoble.St.Martin.heres.xls","Grenoble_1968-2005.csv","historiques Bordeaux et Dinard.txt","Hyeres_2007-2009.csv","Istres.csv","Istres.txt","La-Rochelle_1961-2005.csv","La-Rochelle_Aerodrome_2007-2009.csv","La.Rochelle.xls","Le.Puy.xls","Le.Touquet.xls","Lille.xls","Lille_1961-2005.csv","losvari.11069001.txt","losvari.14137001.txt","losvari.17300001.txt","losvari.31069001.txt","losvari.33529001.txt","losvari.62826001.txt","losvari.64549001.txt","losvari.76552001.txt","losvari.78621001.txt","Luxeil.xls","Luxeuil_1961-2005.csv","Lyon.Bron.xls","Lyon_1961-2005.csv","Macon_1994-2005.csv","Macon_2001-2005.csv","Marignane.xls","Marignane_1961-2005.csv","Metz.Frescaty.xls","Metz_1961-2005.csv","Millau.xls","Mise_en_forme.r","Montelimar.xls","Montelimar_1961-2005.csv","Montpellier.xls","Montpellier_1961-2005.csv","Nantes.Bouguenais.xls","Nantes_1961-2005.csv","Nice.xls","Nice_1961-2005.csv","Nimes.Courbessac.xls","Nimes_1961-2005.csv","Orange.xls","Orange_1961-2005.csv","Orleans.xls","Orleans_1961-2005.csv","Paris_1950-2005.csv","Paris1.xls","Pau.Uzein.xls","Pau_03-2006.csv","Pau_1961-2005.csv","Perpignan.xls","Perpignan_1961-2005.csv","Reims.Courcy.xls","Reims_1961-2005.csv","Rennes.St.Jacques.xls","Rennes_1961-2005.csv","Rennes_1961-2005_sauf_2003-2004.csv","Rennes_2003-2004.csv","Rouen.Boos.xls","Rouen_1969-2005.csv","Saint.Brieuc.xls","Saint.Girons.xls","St-Etienne_1961-2005.csv","St-Girons_1961-2005.csv","St-Quentin_1961-2008.csv","St.Auban.xls","St.Etienne.Boutheon.xls","St.Quentin.xls","Strasbourg.Entzheim.xls","Strasbourg_1949-2005.csv","Toulon.xls","Toulon_1961-2005.csv","Toulouse.Blagnac.xls","Toulouse_1961-2005.csv","Tours.xls","Tours_1960-2005.csv")
x <- gsub("^\\p{Ll}.*$|(?:[_.]\\d.*|(?:^\\d+)?\\.[^.]+)$", "", x, perl=TRUE)
x <- x[x != ""]
y <- gsub("[\\W_]", "", x, perl=TRUE)
x[-which(duplicated(y))]
```

#### Variations

These variations are based on the OP's specific requirements. For more details about each variation, please see the **Discrepencies** section under **Results**. Methods below may be combined such that they satisfy multiple discrepencies.

**Method 1**

Adds `|^[\p{Lu}_\d]+` to match any combination of uppercase letters, underscore and digits from the start of the string to the extension.

```
^\p{Ll}.*$|(?:[_.]\d.*|(?:^\d+|^[\p{Lu}_\d]+)?\.[^.]+)$
```

**Method 2**

Adds `|^\p{L}+(?:_\p{L}+)+` to match any letter one or more times, followed by one or more of [an underscore followed by one or more letters]

```
^\p{Ll}.*$|(?:[_.]\d.*|(?:^\d+|^\p{L}+(?:_\p{L}+)+)?\.[^.]+)$
```

---

### Results

**Note**: A few discrepencies exist between the resultset below and your *expected* output.

#### Discrepencies

- `Clermont.Fd`: This is because `Clermond != Clermont`
  (`d` vs `t`).
- `ENVOI_METEO`: See **Variations**: **Method 1**, but it might have negative consequences on valid names, thus I've made this *fix* optional by excluding it from the answer's actual code.
- `Grenoble.St.Martin.heres`: Some of your input includes lowercase letters after `.` (see `Cap.de.la.Heve.Le.Havre`, `Grenoble.le.versoud`, and `Biarritz.anglet`). I'm not sure how you want to differentiate this from the rest of your results.
- `Luxeuil`: Not the same as `Luxeil`, so I don't remove it.
- `Mise_en_forme`: Other valid entries include `_` (see `La-Rochelle_Aerodrome`), thus I'm not sure what the premise is to remove this value from the resultset. If it's because it doesn't contain any `.` or `-` characters, you can use the pattern at **Variations**: **Method 2**.

#### Output

```
Abbeville
Agen
Ajaccio
Auxerre
Bale-Mulhouse
Beauvais
Besancon
Biarritz.anglet
Biarritz
Bonneville
Bordeaux.Merignac
Bordeaux
Boulogne
Bourg-St-Maurice
Bourges
Brest.Guipavas
Brest
Brive
Caen.Carpiquet
Caen
Cap.de.la.Heve.Le.Havre
Carcassonne
Cazaux
Chambery.Aix
Chambery
Charleville.Mezieres
Chartres
Clermond-Fd
Clermont.Fd
Cognac
Colmar
Dijon
Dinard
Dunkerque
Embrun
ENVOI_METEO
Gourdon
Grenoble.le.versoud
Grenoble.St.Geoirs
Grenoble.St.Martin.heres
Grenoble
Hyeres
Istres
La-Rochelle
La-Rochelle_Aerodrome
Le.Puy
Le.Touquet
Lille
Luxeil
Luxeuil
Lyon.Bron
Lyon
Macon
Marignane
Metz.Frescaty
Metz
Millau
Mise_en_forme
Montelimar
Montpellier
Nantes.Bouguenais
Nantes
Nice
Nimes.Courbessac
Nimes
Orange
Orleans
Paris
Paris1
Pau.Uzein
Pau
Perpignan
Reims.Courcy
Reims
Rennes.St.Jacques
Rennes
Rouen.Boos
Rouen
Saint.Brieuc
Saint.Girons
St-Etienne
St-Girons
St-Quentin
St.Auban
St.Etienne.Boutheon
Strasbourg.Entzheim
Strasbourg
Toulon
Toulouse.Blagnac
Toulouse
Tours
```

---

### Explanation

- `x <- gsub("^\\p{Ll}.*$|(?:[_.]\\d.*|(?:^\\d+)?\\.[^.]+)$", "", x, perl=TRUE)` Replace matches with nothing.

  - `^\p{Ll}.*$|(?:[_.]\d.*|(?:^\d+)?\.[^.]+)$` Match either of the following

    - `^\p{Ll}.*$` Match the following (this removes `donnes...` and `hsitorique...` since they begin with lowercase letters)

      - `^` Assert position at the start of the line
      - `\p{Ll}` Match any lowercase letter in any language (Unicode)
      - `.*` Match any character any number of times
      - `$` Assert position at the end of the line
    - `(?:[_.]\d.*|(?:^\d+)?\.[^.]+)$` Match the following (this removes underscore or dots with following digits, file extensions, and number-only named files)

      - `(?:[_.]\d.*|(?:^\d+)?\.[^.]+)` Match either of the following

        - `[_.]\d.*` Match the following

          - `[_.]` Match any character in the set (underscore or dot)
          - `\d` Match a digit
          - `.*` Match any character any number of times
        - `(?:^\d+)?\.[^.]+` Match the following

          - `(?:^\d+)?` Match the following zero or one time

            - `^` Assert position at the start of the line
            - `\d+` Match one or more digits
          - `\.` Match a dot literally
          - `[^.]+` Match any character not present in the set (any character except dot) one or more times
      - `$` Assert position at the end of the line
- `x <- x[x != ""]` Removes empty strings from the vector `x`
- `y <- gsub("[\\W_]", "", x, perl=TRUE)` Copies `x` while replacing all characters that are not word characters as well as underscores with nothing. Alternatively (or if this doesn't always work for you), `[^\p{L}\p{N}]` can be used (which matches any character that is not a letter or number in any language/script - Unicode).

  - For example:

    - `Bale-Mulhouse` becomes `BaleMulhouse`
    - `Bale.Mulhouse` becomes `BaleMulhouse`
- `x[-which(duplicated(y))]` Removes indices where duplicate values were found in `y` (after removing non-alphanumeric characters).

  - For example (see last bullet point's example of `BaleMulhouse`):

    - `BaleMulhouse` duplicate is removed. Duplicates are defined as all duplicates *except* the first of its kind, thus, only the first of a set of duplicates will remain.

Comment: Wow, thank you a lot for this very detailed answer and the explanations.I think I will simply rename by hand some files in the folder to avoid the few discrepancies that are remaining.
As soon as I'll have enough reputation points I will give you a big +1 to your answer.